# The number of elements in $M_n(F)$ and $GL_n(F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> If $F=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field with $p$ elements, then what is the number of elements in:
>   (1) ring $M_n(F)$;
>   (2) group $GL_n(F)$?

I wonder whether it is the same that I just pick up an element from $p$ different numbers in each element of the matrix? Say, there're $n^2$ elements, so the total number of elements for $M_n(F)$ is just $p^{n^2}$?
For (2), I just don't know how to eliminate those singular matrices.

Comment: $M_n(F) = F^{n \times n}$. For $GL_n(F)$ try first with $n= 2$ (think to linearly independent rows)

Comment: Hint : $(2)$ is equivalent to count the number of basis of $(\mathbb{F}_p)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about $M_n(F)$. The order of $GL_n(F)$ is $(p^n-1)(p^n-p)\cdots(p^n-p^{n-1})$. A proof can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields).

Answer (score 0):

The trick to counting invertible matrices is the following theorem:

> A square matrix is invertible if and only if its columns are an ordered basis

and so you can count ordered bases. The easiest way to do so is to construct an ordered linearly independent set one at a time, and at each step determining how many vectors *don't* extend the basis. e.g. the first choice has $p^n - 1$ options, because you can't start with $0$.